# Is it correct to say- "I love him and I admire him since I know him."?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to say- "I love him and I admire him since I know him." ?

Comment: I think "because" would be more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer is correct, as long as his meaning is what is intended.

If, on the other hand, you have admired and loved him for as long as you have known him, you could say "I have loved and admired him ever since I met him," or "I have loved and admired him (for) as long as I have known him."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explain the reason why you love and admire him, this is correct, but I would re-phrase it a little bit:

> I love and admire him since I know him (well?)